# Socket io não encontra a rota

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket, websocket, socket.io

tudo bem?

Estou instanciando o socket como IO e ao utilizar o io.on('connection', function()) ele acaba não caindo dentro do meu io.on ao acessar a pagina, ele não retorna nenhuma mensagem e no modo debug ele nem chega a passar pela rota, poderiam me dar alguma luz? Obrigado!

Segue projeto:
https://github.com/henrique-nofv/socketIoChat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Henrique, observando seu código no github HTML com o socketio do client (public/index.html):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Percebi que você importou a biblioteca do socketio mas não chamou a mesma para fazer a conexão com o seu server.

Exemplo:

```
<script>
  const socket = io('http://localhost');
</script>
```